# Android corrupting photos 1 minute after capture

Tags: photos, images

Sorry this is a question but I'm exhausted all other avenues.

I am running Android 4.3 on a Samsung S4 GT-I9505 happily for the past 17 months. I have not changed anything for a long time, it's been rooted since I got it. Nothing new installed or removed lately either.

Starting last Saturday, after I capture an image it's there and visible in the Gallery and any other app that wants to use it, for instance email or uploading to facebook. After a minute passes the file slowly gets corrupted and then is unusable by any app and shows as a "broken image" icon in the gallery.

This is infuriating that it's taking time to corrupt and not instant.

Anyone any idea where to even begin looking at the cause? I'm a software engineer of many platforms including Android so don't cradle the answer.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried capturing pictures with other camera apps? Where does the images you take stored? Internal or external sd card.?

Comment: External. I will try taking it with another app right now.

Comment: You may also want to try removing your external sd card first and take pictures. This would automatically store pictures in your internal memory.(Just to make sure your problem is with the memory card)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SD card was dying. It stopped writing completely shortly afterwards a new card was the only solution.